# Wait After While Loop

Tags: swift

I have a while loop thats going too fast so I want to make it happen every second or so. I have this right now:

```
while (i == 1, ) {
    println("printed")
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517632/how-to-create-a-delay-in-swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NSTimer` and schedule an action each second:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "yourMethodToCall", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func yourMethodToCall(){
    println("each second")
}
```