# How to implement two default cells of tableview one after the another with animation with time duration?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have succesfully loaded these two default cells of tableview. But my problem is I have to animate these two cells.For example one custom cell will load first then after 1 minutes another cell will load.Now new loaded cell of tableview  appear on the top.

I have use  cell will display method for animation but nothing happened.How to do this type of animation with time duration.

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        previousIndexPath = indexPath
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(someSelector), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)    
    }

Comment: func someSelector() {
        if  previousIndexPath?.row == 0 {
            let identifier = "TableViewCell2"
            let cell = self.homeTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: previousIndexPath!) as UITableViewCell
            cell.alpha = 0.0
            cell.isHidden = true
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                cell.alpha = 1.0
                 cell.isHidden = false
            })
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of libraries out there for animations like [this](https://github.com/MengTo/Spring) , also you can try with core graphics animation which will be a little time consuming.

for waiting 1 minute use the [timer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37248287/6700895)

or

use UNIX function [sleep](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sleep.3.html)

```
sleep(4)
```

or

**Swift 3**

With GCD:

```
let delayInSeconds = 4.0
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + delayInSeconds) {

    // here code perfomed with delay

}
```

Comment: Nstimer is not working . When I try to use nstimer then application is crashed