# Can't find a way to implement a wait function in my Swift code

Tags: swift, wait

I can't find a way to implement a wait function, I'm using swiftforwindows and no examples online have been able to solve it so far. It's Swift 4.2

The class is basically an array that when a function is called each index on the array gets a constant value deducted. the tick function is what is being called. I'm new to Swift.

```
class resProj {

var list = [1,1,1,1]
var projReq = [100,200,300,50]
var completed = false

func tick(){
    for count in 0..<projReq.count{
        if projReq[count] <= list[count]{
            projReq[count] = 0
        }
        else if projReq[count] > list[count]{
            projReq[count] -= list[count]
        }
    }
    print(projReq)
}


init(
    mathsP      mathsIn:    Int,
    scienceP    sciecnceIn: Int,
    enginerP    enginerIn:  Int,
    businessP   businessIn: Int) {

    self.list [0] = mathsIn
    self.list [1] = sciecnceIn
    self.list [2] = enginerIn
    self.list [3] = businessIn

    }
 }

var spaceElev = resProj(
mathsP:     10,
scienceP:   20,
enginerP:   30,
businessP:  5)

var x = false

while x == false{
//wait function here pls//
print("tick", terminator:"?")
let y = readLine()
if y == "y"{
    spaceElev.tick()
}
else{
    print("gotta put y")
    }
var templist = spaceElev.projReq
var templistcount = 0
templistcount = templist.count
for loop in 0..<templistcount{
    if templist[loop] == 0{
        templistcount -= 1
    }
}
if templistcount == 0 {
    x = true
    print("project completed")
}
}
     }
```

Where it says `//wait function here pls//` I would like to make the program wait for 1 second.

Comment: Try `sleep(1)`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Basically, you should never try to make your app stop for some time. What you really need is to schedule code to be executed after 1 second. For example using a `Timer`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517632/how-to-create-a-delay-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of way to do this but most common way is create a *completion function*. For example:

```
func doSth(_ someParameter: String, _ completion: ()->()) {
    print(someParameter)
    //  After your code is finish call completion
    completion()
}
```

And when you call (there is two way to call):

```
doSth("Done") {
    print("You can be sure that this block will work after your func finish")
}
```

or you can simply create another func and send it as a parameter.

You can also use `DispatchQueue`:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+1) {
    // put your func here...
}
```

Comment: I got the first 2 code snippets to work but it did not add a delay. this is swift for windows not Xcode swift. idk if that makes a diffrence

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use the UNIX-Functin `func sleep(_: UInt32) -> UInt32`.
In your case use `sleep(1)` to wait one second.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Grand Central Dispatch or perform.

GCD solution:

```
let delayInSeconds = 1
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delayInSeconds) {
print("tick", terminator:"?")
}
```

If you want to learn more about Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) I suggest you read through this:
[Grand Central Dispatch - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Central_Dispatch)

[Grand Central Dispatch Tutorial - Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5370-grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-for-swift-4-part-1-2)

**Perform solution:**

Create a function like this:

```
@objc func delayedFunc() {
//write the code here that you want to execute with a one second delay
}
```

Then call this where you want the delayed function to execute:

```
let delayInSeconds = 1
perform(#selector(delayedFunc), with: nil, afterDelay: delayInSeconds)
```

Comment: suing these game me:error: use of unresolved identifier 'DispatchQueue'
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delayInSeconds) {

Comment: oh yes I only see now that you are using Swift on Windows. GCD is Apple technology so you can't find it on Windows I suppose. 
Have you tried the perform method? I think that should still work.

Comment: I don't know what that is I have 1 day EXP of this, do you have a link to a page so I can learn about it?

Comment: I updated my answer! Try the "perform solution" and let me know if it worked.

Comment: it game me this:C:\Users\thoma\Desktop\1984\Swift\GAME\Swift\Game\test.swift:3:7: error: 
objc can only be used with members of classes, objc protocols, and concrete extensions of classes
objc func delayedFunc() {
~~~~~~^
C:\Users\thoma\Desktop\1984\Swift\GAME\Swift\Game\test.swift:8:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'perform'
perform(#selector(delayedFunc), with: nil, afterDelay: delayInSeconds)
^~~~~~~
SwiftMinGWCrt.perror:1:13: note: did you mean 'perror'?
public func perror(_ _ErrMsg: UnsafePointer<Int8>!)
            ^


Compilation Failed.

Comment: had to remove the "at" because stack overflow but its there. the code was:import Foundation

@objc func delayedFunc() {
 print("oh hi Idem")
}

let delayInSeconds = 1
perform(#selector(delayedFunc), with: nil, afterDelay: delayInSeconds)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `RunLoop` class:

```swift
func wait(for interval: TimeInterval) {
    RunLoop.current.run(until: Date() + interval)
}
```