# Delay a function call - difference in asyncAfter and sleep

Tags: swift, delay, thread-sleep

What is difference between

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
    performTask()
}
```

and

```
Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)
performTask()
```

Comment: I think this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32696605/10564881
The short answer is that `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` does not block the thread from doing other work, meanwhile `Thread.sleep` blocks the thread

Comment: Unlike `asyncAfter` `sleep` blocks the current thread. if *delay a function call* is an attempt to make an asynchronous task synchronous don't use any of them.