# Start the transition after 5 seconds

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Hello how to make the transition

```
let transitionType = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration (2.0)
```

started after 5 seconds?

my code:

```
let nextLevel = level2(size: size)
nextLevel.scaleMode = scaleMode
let transitionType = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(2.0)       
view?.presentScene(nextLevel,transition: transitionType)
```

Comment: You could use a NSTimer for that. Similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007518/how-can-i-use-nstimer-in-swift).

Comment: @Jan Trienes, it's not a good idea to use an `NSTimer` with Sprite Kit - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978209/spritekit-creating-a-timer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`SKAction.waitForDuration`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/waitForDuration:) combined with [`SKAction.runBlock`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/runBlock:) in an [`SKAction` sequence](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/sequence:):

```
let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(5)
let action = SKAction.runBlock {
    view?.presentScene(nextLevel, transition: transitionType)
}

self.runAction(SKAction.sequence([wait, action]))
```