# Auto refresh using swift

Tags: swift, parsing, refresh

I know how to use pull to refresh and how to make a refresh button. I am just wondering if anyone knows how or can link me to a page that teaches me how auto refresh a page. Like every 15 seconds to automatically refresh.

Comment: You can use a timer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007518/how-can-i-use-nstimer-in-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var yourButton: UIButton!
var timer: NSTimer!
var refresher: UIRefreshControl!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    yourButton.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    refresher.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(15.0, target: self, selector:"refreshEvery15Secs", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func refreshEvery15Secs(){
    // refresh code
}

func refresh(sender: AnyObject){

     refreshEvery15Secs() // calls when ever button is pressed
}
```

Comment: My code is trying to do this, and it is running it. But I get thread 1 signal SIGABRT error. Itt says I have an unrecognized selector.

Comment: You commented on both of our answer. If you're using mine, I made a few edits.

Comment: Because I tried both and both gave me the same error haha

Comment: @JCDOSAJ I don't think you need `timer: NSTimer` in the parameters of `refreshEvery15Secs`. It should just be `func refreshEvery15Secs()` The `action` for the `UIRefreshControl` needs a function with `(sender: AnyObject)` as the parameters.

Comment: Caleb is right, I wrote it from memory but i made some changes again.

Comment: @JCDOSAJ I made an edit to the answer. The code above should work.

Comment: I have all this code, it just isnt firing. I tried putting refresher.beingRefreshing() in the refreshEvery15Secs func but it causes the EXC_BREAKPOINT error.

Answer (score -1):

create `NSTimer` to fire every 15 seconds

```
let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(15, target: self, selector: "refreshData:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

do the refresh in a callback function

```
func refreshData(timer: NSTimer){
    refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
}
```

Comment: My code is trying to do this, and it is running it. But I get thread 1 signal SIGABRT error. Itt says I have an unrecognized selector.