# Repeat function using NSTimer fails with target: self in Swift

Tags: swift, nstimer

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007518/how-can-i-use-nstimer-in-swift) and tried to copy the code to my Xcode project, but I'm getting the following error message.

> error: use of unresolved identifier 'self'

What's the right way?

**EDIT:** Here the code, tested in a playground:

```
    //: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa
import Foundation

func sayHello() {
    print("hello World")
}

var SwiftTimer = NSTimer()
SwiftTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target:self, selector: Selector("sayHello"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: Post some code of your project

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano I edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually using uppercase to the properties name it's considered as a bad attitude, you should use swiftTimer.

These expressions are not allowed ad the top level:

```
var swiftTimer = NSTimer()
swiftTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target:self, selector: Selector("sayHello"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

You must put it in a function like for example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var swiftTimer = NSTimer()
        swiftTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target:self, selector: Selector("sayHello"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`self` refers to the object for which a method (a function defined within a class) is defined, so can only be used in a method. (It is the equivalent of `this` in C++/Java/Javascript.) In your code, `sayHello()` is a global function, not a method, so there is no `self` to refer to.

In order for the `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval()` function call to work with those arguments, it must be called within an instance method so that there is a `self`, and that class must have a method named `sayHello()`.

You could also change the `target:` to another object as long as that object has a `sayHello()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Basically an asynchronous timer doesn't work in a Playground and a since the top level of a Playground isn't a class there is no `self` property.

To test `NSTimer` in a Playground

- Wrap the timer in a class.
- Import `XCPlaygound`.
- Add `XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true` to enable  support of asynchronous tasks.