# NSTimer Function Not Being Called

Tags: macos, nstimer

I am creating and attempting to use an NSTimer with the following code:

```
import Foundation

class TimerCallbacker {

    init() {
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: #selector(TimerCallbacker.timerDidFire(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func timerDidFire(timer: NSTimer) {
        print("hi")
    }
}

let timerCallbacker = TimerCallbacker()
```

The program runs for a second without any console output and then ends, instead of the expected functionality of printing "hi" every second.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24007862/1195661) for a proper integration. Your last line is misplaced. It is out of the class declaration but should be in there.

Comment: I just made an update to the code. Please check it. :)

Answer (score -1):

Be sure to enable the [Apple NSTimer Library for Java Implementation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207012) through your **Xcode CLI interface**! Use the library in the following way:

```
let timer = new NSTimer().delay(2000, "hours");
```

Comment: That link is for charging AirPods.