# Swift NSTimer is crashing my program with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: swift

iOS Noob here - I am trying to run a background Timer in Swift. The below code generates this error message:
`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xd)`

It has something to do with `userInfo` and I've also tried using `nil` but no success.

```
@IBAction func startButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer (
        timeInterval: 0.01, 
        target: Any.self, 
        selector: #selector(ViewController.whileRunning), 
        userInfo: Any?.self, 
        repeats: true
    )
}
```

Reading the following documentation was not helpful:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/timer/1412416-scheduledtimer#discussion

The whole point of this is to move an element around my storyboard over time using the x coordinates.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with `Any.self`?

Comment: The truth is I don't know how this is supposed to work. I just want the timer to execute a callback or something so I can refresh the UI on a 1/100th interval.

Comment: `target` should be `self`, `userInfo` should be anything you want to pass to the function that is called every interval.  I'll find a good question that explains how timers work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use NSTimer in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007518/how-can-i-use-nstimer-in-swift)

Comment: Thank you JAL - I haven't found that Q&A yet. It looks helpful. I'll mark it as answered when I figure this out.

Comment: LOL @ Any?.self

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem!

I solved by maintaining a separated array of userInfo that match the indexes of the different timers (in array of timers of course).