# Background timer for ios9

Tags: ios, background, swift3

I have a background process in my app. Here's the code:

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func startTimer() {
    timer2?.invalidate()
    timer2 = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true, block: { (t) in
        if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .background {
            NSLog("tic background \(UIApplication.shared.backgroundTimeRemaining)")

            if UIApplication.shared.backgroundTimeRemaining < 10 {

            }

        }

    })
    timer2?.fire()
}
```

However, it works only in iOS10. Is there a way to rewrite in for previous versions of iOS?

Comment: What is the issue in iOS9?

Comment: 'scheduledTimer(withTimerInterva:repeats:block)' is only available on ios 10 or newer

Comment: See; http://stackoverflow.com/a/24007862/1457385

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no block based timer API on ios9 or below.

either use a method as a callback instead of a block OR use a third party solution like e.g. BlocksKit (there are hundreds)

Id go with a method:

```
func startTimer() {
    timer2?.invalidate()
    timer2 = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.timerFired(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    timer2?.fire()
}

@objc
func timerFired(_ timer: Timer) {
    NSLog("tic")

    if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .background {
        NSLog("tic background \(UIApplication.shared.backgroundTimeRemaining)")

        if UIApplication.shared.backgroundTimeRemaining < 10 {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, again. Thanks for you answer. This feels to be the right solution. However, I can't write the working code with a callback. Can you give me more details for my particular case? Thanks

Comment: Huge thanks! I've been struggling to make it work. You just gave me the solution! May I ask you what this part means (_:) in #selector?

Comment: @AntonPlatonov sure, that is the name of the argument - In swift, #selector takes the full method signature: `#selector(MyClass.myMethod(myArg1:myArg2:myArg3:)`