# How can I loop an action using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to execute a function every 10 seconds, using swift. But i dont know how to proceed. I know I have to use a timer, but didnt find useful tutorial for this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a NSTimer and a RunLoop:

```
    func startTimer(){
        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10, target: self, selector: #selector(yourFunction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
    }

    func yourFunction(){
        //doStuff
    }
```

Comment: is this going to be repeated over 10 seconds?

Comment: @coopergamez Yes, it has the repeats attribute as true

Answer (score 3):

Do read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007518/how-can-i-use-nstimer-in-swift).

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //Swift 3 selector syntax
    var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.4, target: self, selector: #selector(self.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true);
    //Swift 2.2 selector syntax
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: #selector(MyClass.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    //Swift <2.2 selector syntax
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

// must be internal or public. 
func update() {
    // Something cool
}
```