# using timer to set local notification every X seconds

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

i am trying to make an alarm app by setting new local notifications every X seconds when a `Set` button is pressed and stopping when the user taps a `Stop` button.

using `Timer()`, i am currently able to set the local notification but it doesn't repeat as I would like. it only repeats when i go into the app and back to the previous screen via the `Home` button. also, it only repeats once by doing that.

is there any way to have the user press the `Set` button once and have the notifications keep firing no matter if you're in the app/outside the app and only stopping when the user presses the `Stop` button?

my code as follows:

```
class LocalNotificationViewController: UIViewController {
    var timer = Timer()

    func runTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: (#selector(self.setLocalNotification)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func setLocalNotification() {
        //        timeEntered = time.text!
        //        let hrMin = timeEntered.components(separatedBy: ":");
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Test Local Notification"
        content.subtitle = "Testing..."
        content.body = "Testing..."
        content.badge = 1
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: "alarm.aiff");

            trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false);

            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "timerDone", content: content, trigger: trigger)

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    }

    var timeEntered: String = "";
    var trigger: UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger? = nil;
    @IBOutlet var time: UITextField!;

    @IBAction func setNotification(_ sender: Any) {
        runTimer()
    }

    @IBAction func stopRepeat(_ sender: Any) {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
```

Comment: Is your `LocalNotificationViewController`instance retained while you are waiting for the repeated notifications, or is it by chance dismissed and with it your timer?

Comment: what do u mean retained? like am i currently at that view controller? if thats what u mean then no it is not retained.

Comment: By retained I mean: Is any object of your app holding a pointer to your `LocalNotificationViewController` instance, i.e. do you have in your app delegate or in another class that persists while you are waiting for your notifications, something like `var localNotificationViewController: LocalNotificationViewController?` to which your `LocalNotificationViewController` instance is assigned? If not, your `LocalNotificationViewController` instance will be released, i.e. will no longer exist, including the timer that should fire repeatedly.

Comment: that's helpful. how would you recommend doing this? in `AppDelegate.swift` i made a var as `var instance: LocalNotificationViewController?`. Then in `LocalNotificationViewController`'s `viewDidLoad()`, i added `AppDelegate.instance = self;` but got the error `Instance member 'instance' cannot be used on type 'AppDelegate'` ideas?