# Check if username is in Firestore Database while editing UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, uitextfield

I am trying to check wether or not a username is taken while the user types in the name. Currently I have these two functions that are working almost the way I would want it to work but not 100% correctly:

`textFieldDidChange`:

```
 @objc private func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {

    switch textField {

    // ... //    
    case usernameTextField:
        if textField.text?.isEmpty == false {
            checkUsername(field: textField.text!) { (success) in
                print(textField.text!)
                if success == true {
                    // username is taken
                    print("Username is taken")
                    self.setupUsernameTextField()
                    self.checkUsernameImage.image = UIImage(named: "false")
                    self.checkUserNameLabel.text = "Benutzername ist bereits vergeben"
                } else {
                    // username is not taken
                    print("Username is not taken")
                    self.checkUsernameImage.image = UIImage(named: "correct")
                    self.checkUserNameLabel.text = "gültiger Benutzername"
                }
            }
        }else {
            self.checkUsernameImage.image = UIImage(named: "false")
            self.checkUserNameLabel.text = "kein gültiger Benutzername"
        }
    default:
        break
    }

}


// helper function to check if username is in databse -> later in Datahandler
func checkUsername(field: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let collectionRef = db.collection("users")
    collectionRef.whereField("username", isEqualTo: field).getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting document: \(err)")
        } else if (snapshot?.isEmpty)! {
            completion(false)
        } else {
            for document in (snapshot?.documents)! {
                if document.data()["username"] != nil {
                    completion(true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem:** If you type in something quite fast or if your internet connection isn't very good it displays `Username is not taken` when it actually is.

If you look at the Instagram-App, they are doing it the perfect way:

1. type something in, even fast
2. after you stop typing for maybe a second, a `loading indicator` pops up and only then u get feedback wether or not the username is taken
3. type something in while `loading indicator` is active, it stops and only starts again if you stop typing again.

My Question: How do I realize that??? Like how do I know when the user "stops" typing but the `textField` is still `editing` ? I tried it with `shouldEndEditing` but that only works if the `textfield` is no longer selected and thats not what I would like to achieve. In the end I would like to have the exact same process as in the Instagram app.

Any ideas on how to realize that??

Comment: I suggest looking into implementing a "debounce".

Comment: This is done with a simple timer between keystrokes. If there's another keystroke while the timer is running, reset the timer. When the timer expires, lookup the existing string. You could do this within `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` for example

Comment: uff never used a timer or `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` . Could you maybe elaborate on this? :) I think that's exactly what I need!

Comment: When responding to a comment, be sure to include the @ symbol before the persons name, like @Jay - that will notify the person. See the docs for [UITextField](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield) for a link to that function. If you need a timer, then see [Timer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer) and then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007518/how-can-i-use-timer-formerly-nstimer-in-swift) for a bunch of examples - be sure to look at the Swift 4 and Swift 5 answers.

Comment: @Jay thanks! still not quite sure what `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` is doing. Can't I just use a `didChange`-method (add target to textfield) use for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With @Jays suggestion I was able to make it work:

My `textField` is connected with a `didChange` method which looks like this:

```
timer.invalidate() // reset timer

// start the timer
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(timerAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

And the connected `timerAction`-method looks like this:

```
// called every time interval from the timer
@objc func timerAction() {
    checkUsername(field: usernameTextField.text!) { (success) in
        print(self.usernameTextField.text!)
        if success == true {
            // username is taken
            print("Username is taken")
            self.setupUsernameTextField()
            self.checkUsernameImage.image = UIImage(named: "false")
            self.checkUserNameLabel.text = "Benutzername ist bereits vergeben"
            // stop timer
            self.timer.invalidate()
        } else {
            // username is not taken
            print("Username is not taken")
            // stop timer
            self.timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
}
```

Works exactly the way I want it to work, thanks for the help:)

Comment: Hey, remember to accept your own answer after [48 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) in order to help the community in case somebody else has the same issue as you.